# start wmii from ~/.xinitrc

Tags: linux, window-manager, xinit, x

What is the right way to start `wmii` window manager from ~/.xinitrc? I put `exec wmii` however it doesn't seem to pick up configuration.

Comment: I've added `exec /etc/X11/wmii/wmiirc &` but now it returns with error:  `wmiir: fatal: can't mount: Connection refused`

Answer (score -1):

Try this, see if it works:

```
startx /usr/bin/wmii
```